# MongoDB query question: how should I express selection by one field has a value and another field is not set?

Tags: mongodb

I'm fairly new to Mongo and I don't quite understand:

why is it, that for the following items in the collection test2, the first query works but the second doesn't?
And why is it that the query gives me only the _id of the user, and not the entire contents of the user, while it does give me all the information of that uses invites?

Queries:

```
db.test2.find({"invitations.acceptedDate": {$exists: false}}, {"invitations.code":"codeAA"})
db.test2.find({"invitations.code":"codeAA"}, {"invitations.acceptedDate": {$exists: false}})
```

Is this even the right way of expressing the query in Mongo? The query I'm trying to write is:

"Please give me a list of Users that have sent an invitation using code 'codeAA' where the invitation has not been claimed (invite does not contain an acceptedDate)"

Data:

```
[{
    "username": "userA",
    "password": "secretA",
    "invitations": [{
        "code": "codeAA",
        "emailSentTo": "test1@me.com",
    },{
        "code": "codeAB",
        "emailSentTo": "test@me.com",
        "acceptedDate": "20110424"
    }]},
{
    "username": "userB",
    "password": "secretB",
    "invitations": [{
        "code": "codeBA",
        "emailSentTo": "test1@me.com",
    },{
        "code": "codeBB",
        "emailSentTo": "test@me.com",
    }]},
{
    "username": "userC",
    "password": "secretC",
    "invitations": [{
        "code": "codeCA",
        "emailSentTo": "test1@me.com",
    },{
        "code": "codeAA",
        "emailSentTo": "test@me.com",
        "acceptedDate": "20110424"
    }]},
{
    "username": "userD",
    "password": "secretD",
    "invitations": [{
        "code": "codeDA",
        "emailSentTo": "test1@me.com",
    },{
        "code": "codeDB",
        "emailSentTo": "test@me.com",
    }]
}]
```

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a look into the mongodb docs for the [find method](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-FieldSelection) you will see that it expects your query as the first argument and a list of the fields to be selected in the second. So in your first call to find

```
db.test2.find({"invitations.acceptedDate": {$exists: false}}, {"invitations.code":"codeAA"})
```

only `"invitations.acceptedDate": {$exists: false}` applies to your query but `{"invitations.code":"codeAA"}` is not part of the condition. You probably want to put all your conditions into one query object:

```
{
    "invitations.acceptedDate": {$exists: false},
    "invitations.code":"codeAA"
}
```

and pass it as first and only argument to find.

It may further be that you only get the _id of the users because you misapplied the second attribute of find somehow.

Edit:
If you want docs with a single array element matching more than one condition use [$elemMatch](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch). So for your question:

> "Please give me a list of Users that
>   have sent an invitation using code
>   'codeAA' where the invitation has not
>   been claimed (invite does not contain
>   an acceptedDate)"

your query should be something like:

```
{
    invitations: {
        $elemMatch: {
            code: "codeAA",
            acceptedDate: {$exists: false}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for explaining why I get this result. :-) However, I don't get that that one query object actually matches correctly: it'll match "userC" as well, even though it doesn't have an invitation where the code is codeAA and without an acceptedDate.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a field filter as second parameter to find(). 
The complete queries is always passed as *first* parameter.